# Proof of a Property of Inner Product Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Is it true that $$\langle Au,Av\rangle = \langle u,A^{*}Av \rangle$$

for some inner product space $V,$ vectors $u,v$ and a square matrix $A$?

For the standard inner product, this is trivially true if $A$ is Hermitian, but what about other cases?

**What if the inner product is not standard?**

**What if $A$ is not Hermitian?**

**When does the above hold true?**

$A*$ refers to the conjugate transpose of $A.$

Comment: What exactly is your definition of the adjoint $A^*$? Are you just taking $A^*$ to mean the conjugate transpose matrix of the matrix $A$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Since your space is finite dimensional there is essentially only one inner product on it: any other inner product gives  a space that is isometrically isomorphic to the one with the usual Euclidean inner product.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree! Well, can this be proved then?

Comment: Standard notation is not $<Au,Av>=\cdots,$ but $\langle Au,Av\rangle=\cdots. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, on a finite dimensional space $V$ you have essentially the euclidean inner product. This means that any inner product on $V$ can be written as

$$ \langle u, v \rangle_M = u^\ast M v $$

for a hermitian positive definite matrix $M$ (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244528/is-any-inner-product-given-by?rq=1)).
But $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_M)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_E)$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_E$ denotes the euclidean inner product. To see this note that $M$ can be written as a square of a hermitian matrix $M = N \cdot N.$
Then
$$ (V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_M) \to (V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_E); \quad  x \mapsto Nx $$
gives an isometric isomporphism, as 
$$ \langle u, v\rangle_M = u^\ast M v = u^\ast NN v = \langle Nu, Nv \rangle_E. $$

Now we show the desired property for the euclidean inner product, which is

$$ \langle u, v \rangle = u^\ast v $$
for arbitrary $u, v \in V.$

Thus 
\begin{align*}
\langle Au, Av \rangle = (Au)^\ast Av = u^\ast A^\ast Av = \langle u, A^\ast Av \rangle.
\end{align*}

Comment: Could you show that there's only one type of inner product?

Comment: Yes, edited a bit.